# Foreach loop takes last value only

Tags: php

I am new in PHP and I have little problem. I have code like this:

```
$file = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];

$chk_ext = explode(".",$file);

if(strtolower($chk_ext[1]) == "txt")
{

    $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $array = array( $data[0]);
        foreach( $array as $value )
        {
            $number=$value;
        }

        $obj=new Sender("$number");
    }

    header("location:bulk.php?msg=send");
}
else
{
    header("location:bulk.php?invalid=file");
    exit();

}
$obj->Submit ();
```

Problem is that only last value comes out from text file in `$obj=new Sender("$number");`, please help me out.

Comment: Explain by your own words how `foreach` works please. And what your particular `foreach` loop does

Comment: foreach($array as $value), set $number = $value. i wonder why $number only holds the last value.

Answer (score 2):

fgetcsv() already return an array so: `$array = array( $data[0]);` just means that you only retrieve the first element of the array of fields which is $data.
In the foreach loop you should just replace the $array variable with $data.
The loop woould then look like this:

```
foreach( $data as $value )
    {
        $number=$value;
    }

    $obj=new Sender("$number");
```

means that for every element in $data, you hold it inside $number, loops again and put it again in $number overwriting it.
After the foreach loop the value of $number would be the last field of the row.

You should just put the line `$obj=new Sender("$number");` inside the loop, so that every element of every row would be put in Sender.

Answer (score 1):

No surprise. You loop over all the values, continually overwriting `$number` with the most recently retrieved value. When the loop exits, you end up with only the last one.

Probably you want something more like:

```
foreach($array as $value) {
   $obj = new Sender($value);
}
```

your code also makes very little sense. You take an uploaded file, presumably CSV, read a line from it, extract the FIRSt value from that line. force the value into an array, then read back that ONE value in the array (the **ONLY** value in the array), and do something with it.

Even if your foreach wasn't overwriting the value, you still only have one single value to loop on anyways.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you assign a new value to `$number` in each iteration. Either you need to append to that variable (`$number .= $value`) or you need to add it to an array (`$number[] = $value`).

Comment: appending the number doesn't make much sense here.  Instantiating the new object should be moved up into the loop.   ...but then I don't know what impact that will have on `$obj->Submit ();`.  I suppose the question might Need Clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the contents of number each iteration. You can instead make number an array which stores each value at incrementing elements.

```
foreach( $array as $value )
 {
   $number[]=$value;
 }

$obj=new Sender($number);
```